# Updating partial after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my comments show page I am loading a partial called '_links' and the form to add a new link like this.

**comments/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/newlink', locals: {question:question} %>
<%= render :partial => 'links/form', locals: {question:question} %>
```

**comments/_newlink**

```
<% question.links.each do |link| %>
<%= link.body %>
<% end %>
```

The form looks like this.

**links/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [question, Link.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

I then have a file 'link.js.erb':

**comments/link.js.erb**

```
$('.button').append('<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink')  %>');
```

What I am trying to do is update the _links partial using jquery after someone clicks the submit button but it's not quite working. I believe the jquery is correct and it's a rails issue with where I placed the partials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things which you are missing

a. ***You need to submit your form by ajax so use [`remote: true option`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Unobtrusive+JavaScript)***. Your form should be like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [question, Link.new], remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

b. ***Your form will send a request to create method in your links controller*** so your method should be like this:

```
def create
  @link = Link.new(link_params) 
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @link.save
      format.js  # this will look for a file names create.js.erb in views/links directory
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

c. ***Render your partial and pass locals to it in create.js.erb***:

```
$('.button').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink', locals: {question: @question})  %>"); #notice using double qoutes not single
```

For details you should checkout [`Working with Javascript in Rails`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example)

**Update:**

```
<div id="link">
  <%= render :partial => 'comments/newlink', locals: {question:question} %>
</div>
<div id="link-form">
  <%= render :partial => 'links/form', locals: {question:question} %>
</div>
```

and then to update your partials use this js in create.js.erb

```
 $('#link').html("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink', locals: {question: @question})  %>"); #notice using double qoutes not single
 $('#link-form').html("<%= j (render :partial => 'links/form', locals: {question: @question})  %>"); #notice using double qoutes not single
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. One question though. I already had some js that allowed me to post a new link. Except, when you click submit nothing happens and you have to reload the page to see the new link. I deleted all that js and tried your way because it's much simpler. It works the same however still doesn't reload the partial and the form. Any clue how I could also do this?

Comment: @Loganhinter can you post your logs when you submit your form also do you see any errors in browsers console?

Comment: I am seeing this error in the logs: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `question' for #<#<Class:0x00000102429e58>:0x0000010542ea68>)

Comment: Oops, never mind fixed the above error - was just a spelling mistake.

Comment: @Loganhinter i had a typo in create.js.erb for passing locals. Updated my answer

Comment: I am looking at old railscasts and have tried the following with no success. $('.favouritebuttoncomment').reload("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink', locals: {question: @question})  %>");

Comment: And: $("#new_review")[0].reset(); '#new_review' being the form id.

Comment: @Loganhinter what are you trying to do?

Comment: When i click 'submit' i would like the form to reset and the partial to reload showing the new link. Right now you have to reload the page manually to see the new link.

Comment: @Loganhinter in which partial you have your link and can you edit your question and post it

Comment: The links and the form are rendered in 'comments/_show'.

Comment: @Loganhinter i need to see your comments/_newlink.html.erb you don't have it in your question